# Custom fonts not showing up in emails

Tags: html, fonts, html-email

I am using the following code in emails to import the font 'Open sans' but it shows to users only who have the font already in their systems else it shows the arial font.

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');
    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    table,
    td,
    tr,
    th {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    h2,
    p,
    div {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What email client are you addressing to? Most email readers use HTML engines from the 1990s.

Answer (score 3):

Custom fonts are [not supported in all email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/). It's currently not possible to display webfonts in Outlook, Gmail app, or any webmail client. Be aware that fallback system fonts will display in some email clients no matter what's coded in the email.

However you can specify a webfont for clients that *do* support it, and system fallback fonts for those that don't. Placing something like this inside your `<head>` will get you the best possible coverage:

```
<!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. -->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

More on webfont support in email on [Style Campaign](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/) and [Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers).